# can I deploy maven project in a non-maven server?

Tags: java, maven

I'm learning Maven and I have a simple question. We had a server which runs wildfly and has no maven installed. If I develop a project with maven locally, how do I deploy it to server? Currently we just export project to ear file and copy it to server. Can I do it same way without install maven on the server? Thx.

Comment: Have you already tried it? Yes, you can just copy the war/ear application into your server using sftp or something else, then use one of the already existing several options of Wildfly to deploy your app [documented here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Application%20deployment.html).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need the Maven Wildfly Plugin:

https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/

It can deploy the resulting artifact to a Wildfly server.